# My attempt at proving $S$ compact subset iff $S$ compact metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

$E$ is a metric space and $S \subset E$. The task is to prove $S$ is compact in $E$ iff $S$ itself is a compact metric space.

The definition I am using:

> A metric space $X$ is compact when every covering of $X$ with open subsets, in $X$, has a finite subcovering.

Here's my attempt, would appreciate any feedback.

---

Say first $S$ is compact in $E$. Let $\displaystyle S \subset \bigcup_i Y_i $ be an open covering, where each $Y_i$ is a subset of $S$ also open relative to $S$.

Each $Y_i$ can be written as $Y_i = X_i \cap S$ where each $X_i$ is open relative to $E$. Hence:

> $\displaystyle S \subset \bigcup_i (X_i \cap S) = \left( \bigcup_i X_i \right) \cap S \subset \bigcup_i X_i $

Since $S$ is compact in $E$, we only need finite $i$. Then:

> $S \subset \displaystyle \bigcup_{i \text{ finite}} X_i \implies S \subset \left( \bigcup_{i\text{ finite}} X_i \right) \cap S =  \bigcup_{i\text{ finite}} Y_i  $

So $S$ is itself a compact metric space.

Say next $S$ is a compact metric space. For each subset $Y$ of $E$ also open in $E$, the intersection $Y \cap S$ is a subset open relative to $S$.

Let $S \subset \displaystyle \bigcup_i Y_i $ where each $Y_i$ is a subset of $E$ also open relative to $E$.

Intersecting with $S$ preserves the subset relationship:

> $S \subset \left( \displaystyle \bigcup_i Y_i \right) \cap S = \bigcup_i (Y_i \cap S) = \bigcup_i X_i $.

Each $X_i$ is a subset of $S$ and open relative to $S$. Since $S$ is a compact metric space, we can do fine with finite $i$. Hence:

> $ \displaystyle S \subset \bigcup_{i \text{ finite}} X_i 
> \subset 
> \implies
> S \subset \left( \bigcup_{i \text{ finite}} X_i  \right) \cap S 
> = 
> \bigcup_{i \text{ finite}} ( X_i \cap S ) = \bigcup_{i \text{ finite}} Y_i   $

Hence $S$ is compact in $E$. We are done. $\blacksquare$

Comment: It's correct. The punchline is compactness is not relative property like openness or closedness.

Comment: @Believer Thank you! I was however a bit unsure of the intersections of the type $A \subset B \implies A \subset B \cap A$. If $A$ is a subset of $B$, then $A$ is identically their intersection. But it seemed natural to do here in order to obtain the sought statement.

Comment: @Believer The statement shows that $S$ is compact in a superset $E$ iff it is compact in itself. But what about openness? Isn't an open set also open relative to itself? Does this mean openness is *not* a relative property? I might be missing something here

Comment: Yes, openness is a relative notion.  The interval (0,1) is open in $\mathbb R$ but not in $\mathbb R²$.

Comment: @kapython [0,1] is open in [0,1] but not open in (-1,2). And yes, you are right about intersection thing.

Comment: Thank you both!